# Angular 2 Router 3.0.0 still displaying /#/ hash on route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

My package json has `"@angular/router": "3.0.0"`

My app routes:

```
export const routeConfig: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'use-cases', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'use-cases', component: UseCasesComponent},
  {path: 'add', component: AddComponent},
  {path: 'github', component: RepoBrowserComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: RepoListComponent},
      {path: ':org', component: RepoListComponent,
        children: [
          {path: '', component: RepoDetailComponent},
          {path: ':repo', component: RepoDetailComponent}
        ]
      }]
  }
];
```

But when I access my application I still get `/#/`on the base of the urls.

Comment: Did you enable `HashLocationStrategy` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular by default used `PathLocationStrategy` (without `/#/`).

If you provide

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```

somewhere in your code the router uses `/#/`.

This is usually done because when a server without HTML5 pushState support is used, `PathLocationStrategy` causes `404` errors.
If your sever supports HTML5 pushState, just remove above provider.